# How to find table name on which there is row lock contention happening?

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona

I am using mysql and trying to analyze performance issues on it. I am using `innodb_row_lock_waits` to indicate whether there is a `row lock` contention. The system is used by many consumers so I want to know which table is having the most contention. Is there a way to figure out or print the value of `innodb_row_lock_waits` per table? If not, is there something else which can be used to get this information?

I am using Percona MYSQL 8.0 with innodb as the storage engine.

Comment: I prefer to start with the slowlog.  Delays due to locks tend to show up there as a 
long query time.  Also check `SHOW ENGINE=InnoDB STATUS` to look for deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it use the performance_schema.metadata_locks tables